# How I can change index page in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to put site under maintenance and want to change index page only. I have tried but it effects on other site url like admin. Please let me know another solution.I have done changes in routes.php.

```
Router::connect('/', array(
    'controller' => 'sightings',
    'action' => 'index',
));
```

I have called another method instead of index. But its not working.Please let me know another way in cakephp

Comment: Try to rename your index page and create a new index as your maintenance page and see if that works. Actually the correct approach is changing your route as u did. I can't figure why u said it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created new controller and assigned maintenance view for site. Now, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have hierarchy of .htaaccess files on your server. One of them is at root level. Edit some data and put this code there to redirect your visitors to a maintenance page:

```
# MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have to add RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000 here ip of my site

Comment: I want to redirect each user to maintenance page.

Comment: This is an IP you don't want to redirect to maintenance page. For example, your own ip to use for site test needs.

Comment: It snot working. I have added <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Try with only lines 3, 5 and 7. Check that you have maintenance.html at root.